# Multi-line scrheadings-header intersects section when not preceded by vertical space

Tags: spacing, header-footer, koma-script

When i use the `scrheadings` package and put multiple lines in the header, just like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV8,10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}


\chead{line 1\\ line 2\\ line 3}
\begin{document}
  %\vspace*{0pt}
  \section{Definition}
\end{document}
```

...the section headline intersects the horizontal line of the header!

However, if I make an empty `vspace`, just like this:

```
\chead{line 1\\ line 2\\ line 3}
\begin{document}
  \vspace*{0pt}
  \section{Definition}
\end{document}
```

...everything works fine!

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I do not know the reason for the behavior you encounter, your code uses outdated options and you are being warned about that (in the log):

- `DIV8` should be `DIV=8`
- `scrpage2` is obsolete and should be replaced with `scrlayer-scrpage`

Doing the latter also solves your problem.

New syntax:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV=8,10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}


\chead{line 1\\ line 2\\ line 3}
\begin{document}
  %\vspace*{0pt}
  \section{Definition}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Outdated package `scrheadings` does not adjust the height of the header if needed. You will get `overfull \vbox` warnings and maybe header runs in the text area.
2. `\vspace*{0pt}` does not solve this problem! If a section starts on a new page, there is no additional space before the section heading inserted. Before section headings in the middle of a page there is a `beforeskip` used.

See the second page of the following example:

```
% This is only for demonstration! Suggested is the second example below!
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  DIV=8,% <- use the correct syntax
  10pt,
  %headlines=4 <- this will solve the issue
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mwe}% <- onyl for dummy text
\usepackage{showframe}% <- shows the page layout
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}


\chead{line 1\\ line 2\\ line 3 \\ line 4}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{0pt}
\section{Abschnitt}
\Blindtext
\section{Zweiter Abschnitt}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

But with option `headlines=4` and without `\vspace*{0pt}` you will get the desired result:

[image]

3. As @TeXnician mentioned `scrpage2` is obsolete. You should use its successor `scrlayer-scrpage`. This package adjustes the `\headheight` if needed. But to avoid the warning set either option `headheight` or option `headlines` while loading the class.

Example/Suggestion:

```
\documentclass[
  DIV=8,% <- use correct syntax
  10pt,
  headlines=4%<- this will solve the issue
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mwe}% <- only for dummd text
\usepackage{showframe}% <- shows the page layout
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}% <- replace the outdated scrpage 2

\chead{line 1\\ line 2\\ line 3 \\ line 4}
\begin{document}
\section{Abschnitt}
\Blindtext
\section{Zweiter Abschnitt}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]